# Generalized linear model fit with constraints and poisson error

Tags: r, constraints, regression, poisson

I am currently trying to fit a linear model to count data, where the errors are following a poisson distribution. Namely I would like to minimize the following
        [image]

where I have *i* samples. β is a vector with *m* coefficients and *x* is consisting of *m* independent (explanatory) variables. β should sum up to 1 and each coefficient should be larger than 0.

I am using R and I tried the package glmc without much success. The only example in the documentation is only confusing me, as I don't get how the constraint matrix Amat is enforcing a constraint on the coefficients. Is there any other example I could have a look at or another package?
I also tried solving this analytically with medium success.
Any help is appreciated!

kind regards, Lena

Comment: Please create a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), with sample data, code and expected output.

Comment: If you need basic help with Poisson Regression in R and some examples please try here... https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/poisson-regression/

Comment: Hi everybody I solved it using constrOptim which is much better documented, so I could implement the constraints correctly